# Postgis calculate the distance between points

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table that has more than 15k rows.

The table has locationID, isEmpty, longitude and latitude fields.

I want to calculate the distance between each point has isEmpty field = 1 and the others and insert the result into new table using Postgis.

Please advise what is the best practice for writing sql statement executing this requirement

Comment: You need euclidean distance or routing? If first it's a case of simple join, but... every isEmpty=1 with every other isEmpty=1 or isEmpty=1 with all others? Can you modify tables or have to do this on existing data without modifications? Of course you know that 15k^2-15k=~225M records? You really need this ammount of data? Maybe it'll be better to count it 'on demand'? And if you need routing this ammount of data will count at least few months (using strong server)

Comment: @jendrusk isEmpty has value 0 or 1 number of records with 1 value is about 2000 records and I need to calculate the distance between each point with has isEmpty =1 with all other points because I need to know  every point with isEmpty =1 how many other points within 500 feet from the point

Comment: Yes I can modify the table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thanks for explanations - now it's clearer.

In Postgis you don't have to count all distances to find how many other points are within some distance.

1. Add extension to database

   ```
   CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
   ```
2. Now add a column of type geometry

   ```
   ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN geom geometry;
   ```
3. You'll need some index to

   ```
   CREATE INDEX mytable_geom_idx ON mytable USING gist(geom);
   ```
4. Now populate new column

   ```
   UPDATE mytable SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat),4326);
   ```
5. And now the query:

   ```
   Select a.locationID, count(*)
   from mytable a 
   join mytable b on a.locationID!=b.locationID 
     and ST_Dwithin(a.geom::geography,b.geom::geography,152) 
   where a.isEmpty=1
   group by 1;
   ```

ST_DWithin with geography type is taking distance in meters and 152m~500ft

I didn't test it, so if something will not work please write me a comment

Comment: Thank you for your help the codes work but I had to  reference locationID from what table and I added group by clause